# universal reference for template type error

Tags: c++, rvalue, universal-reference

Excuse the bad title...

So, normally in a function like this:

```
template <class T>
void f(T&& i){
}
```

`T&&` is a universal reference. In a context like this it is an rvalue-reference:

```
template <class T>
struct s{

    void f(T&& t){}

};
```

This makes sense, as `T` is a fixed type relative to `s` of which `f()` is a method.

However, apparently in this context:

```
template <class T, unsigned n>
std::array<T, n>
f(T&&){
}
```

`T&&` is an rvalue-reference as well. This case is different from the above one though. So, what is the reason for `T&&` being an rvalue-reference here as well rather than a universal one?

Comment: can you rephrase that? I don\t understand what you are saying.

Comment: Why do you say `T&&` is an rvalue reference in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you supplied the parameter type explicitly (I am assuming this much, but this is the only way to make your example compile).

`f<int,5>` performs no type deductions at all, and its parameter is `int&&`. There is no reference collapsing going on.

You could work around this by writing the `f` template as such:

```
template<unsigned n, typename T>
array<decay_t<T>, n>
f(T&& t);
```

Now, `t` is a forwarding/universal reference *if you don't provide the second template argument explicitly*.

Comment: I see, yes I supplied it explicitly. Thanks. Will look up that decay function.

Comment: @lotolmencre `decay_t` is there to make sure you don't end up with `T&`, which isn't a legal type for `std::array`